# Military writing bad habits

Tags: verbs

I have been in the military for 20 years and have noticed some recurring constructs in military writing.  *-ING* verbs following *-ED* verbs is very common and looks wrong, but I can't seem to figure out exactly which rule it breaks.

Here's an example:

> Captain Evans managed the schedule, supporting 16 intelligence units with eight instructors across U.S.

I don't think it's a tense issue since *scheduling* refers to a condition that resulted from the past management.  I think this is a compound verb clause with two primary verbs.  If so, do the verb tenses have to agree?

Also, does *supporting* refer to *schedule*?  Would that make this a compound sentence?

Please help me identify everything that's wrong here and help me educate myself and my troops.

Comment: The only thing I see wrong is the lack of an article ("the") before 'U.S.'.

Comment: *Supporting* here is a present participle, a non-finite form; the subordinate clause it heads acts as a supplement which enlarges on the action of its head clause. It's just dandy.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is based on a misconception.

Comment: You spent a day wondering what it's about, right? Cut out the distracting words and it's a simple and very well grammatical sentence. HTH.

Comment: ....unlike "very well grammatical", which is not grammatical at all.

Comment: @fdb Oh, very well. (Get it now?)

Answer (score 2):

In the example given, the pause (comma) implies "while" or "thereby" or the like, which is perfectly correct in modern English. In any case, "supporting 16 intelligence units with eight instructors across [the] U.S." is a participle phrase modifying "Captain Evans".

It could be rephrased: "Captain Evans, supporting 16 intelligence units with eight instructors across the U.S., managed the schedule."

Comment: Or 'Captain Evans, who supported ...,

Comment: Or "Captain Evans, while supporting..." or "Captain Evans, in order to support..." or any number of other combinations. In the end, the comma is probably the most elegant expression of the intended meaning; life in the military tends to cut down on unnecessary things, even words.

Comment: Yeah, military habits = good habits

Answer (score 0):

What is used in this sentence is **adverbial participle**.
The forms of adverbial participle are:

- present: **doing**, **while doing**;
- present perfect **having done**;

I believe your sentence describes action distributed in the past period before the time of speaking: Captain Evans has supported 16 units at different time and different places.

> Captain Evans managed the schedule, **having supported** 16 intelligence units
>   with eight instructors across **the** U.S.

If the situation is that Captain Evans was supporting all the units simultaneously via liaison networks, then '**while supporting**' or '**supporting**', as you have used it, would be proper.

Of course, supporting refers to Captain's action, not the schedule. If referred to 'schedule', coma is not used.